# How should I clear state in componentWillUnmount?

Tags: react-native

I set code like below.

```
componentWillUnmount() { 
    this.setState({'modal':false}) or this.setState({})
}
```

But state is not clear. How can I do this?
I need clear state when leave component.

Comment: Is the method actually called? It will for example not be called when you navigate to a new screen by pushing the new screen. Only when the component is removed.

Comment: For future users: if you're using react-navigation, you can add a listener to "blur" event, to clear the state when the user leaves the screen. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

Answer (score 14):

According to people at Facebook, setState should not be called on componentWillUnmount as the component is about to be destroyed and never remounted. If you just want to "clear" the state, then there is no need for that, as any new instance of the component will have the clear initial state.

See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12111) any issue where this is talked about.

Comment: I want to set a flag so that async APIs responses do not call  setState when component is already unmounted.

Comment: Do not use state in this scenario but a class field (this.isUnmounted instead of this.state.isUnmounted). Equivalent for functionnal component is using a ref.