# How to clear the component stored redux state in componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

> We are storing the data for the particular component in the redux
>   store by using creatStore() and where combining all the component's
>   state by using combineReducers().Now Once we came out of the page we
>   need to clear the state stored using redux. This is not the dublicate
>   question as written in
>   [How should I clear state in componentWillUnmount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936011/how-should-i-clear-state-in-componentwillunmount)
>   because in this question they want to clear the state of the page that
>   they save by using this.state{}.In our scenario we have to clean from
>   global state (redux-stored-state) for the particular component.We want
>   a global solution so that we can apply to all our component.Please
>   assist me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could dispatch a `reset` action in `componentWillUnmount` which would be handled by a corresponding reducer. The reducer would clear the redux state.

To make it global, you might create a higher-order component that would add dispatching of the reset action to the component it's applied to. And you could have one reducer for the whole app to handle reset actions.

Comment: Is it possible to clear the state without any action in the componentWillUnmount itself?

Comment: The state isn't linked to the component, so you have to dispatch an action to do that. That's the difference between internal and global state.
Why would you want to do this without any action anyway ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I can implement this global reset reducer and the HOC with a minimal example?

Answer (score 0):

you need to import actions of component global store:

```
    import {
  fetchCountries,
  fetchResellers,
  selectCountry
} from "../points-of-sale/actions";
```

I use @Container decorator,

```
@Container({
  props: state => ({
    error: state.product.error,
    product: state.product.product,
    fetched: state.product.fetched,
    locale: state.i18n.locale,
    countries: state.pointsOfSale.countries,
    resellers: state.pointsOfSale.resellers,
    availableCountries: state.pointsOfSale.availableCountries,
    selectedCountry: state.pointsOfSale.selectedCountry,
    selectedResellerType: state.pointsOfSale.selectedResellerType,
    selectedResellers: state.pointsOfSale.selectedResellers,
    menuFixed: state.layout.menuFixed
  }),

  actions: {
    ...actions,

    fetchCountries,
    fetchResellers,
    selectCountry
  }
})
```

here imports actions or stores for another components...
and later only you need use de action to call the apropiate reducer

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    if (
      !this.props.product ||
      this.props.product.slug != this.props.params.product
    ) {
      await this.props.fetchProduct(this.props.params.product);
    }
    if (!this.props.countries.fetched) {
      await this.props.fetchCountries();
    }

    if (!this.props.resellers.fetched) {
      await this.props.fetchResellers();
    }

    this.props.getMenuFixed();



  }
```

and if dou you want clean when the component is unmount you can call to global action that change state of anyone of your components

```
  async componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("componente se esta desmontando");
    await this.props.setErrorDefaultValue();
  }
```